# Scan bluetooth low energy using hcitool?

Tags: linux, shell, ubuntu, bluetooth, bluetooth-lowenergy

When I run this command which makes the ble device scanning for just 5 seconds only:

```
$ sudo timeout 5s hcitool -i hci0 lescan
```

the output is shown in the terminal screen.

But when I redirect the output to a file to save the addresses of the advertising devices, every time I run the command I find the file is empty and the output isn't visible in the terminal nor in the file.

The command I used:

```
$ sudo timeout 5s hcitool -i hci0 lescan > file.txt
```

What do I have to do in order to make `hcitool` correctly redirect its ouput to the file?

Comment: `hcitool` is not being developed anymore and runs with libbluetooth. In my opinion you would be better off using `bluetoothctl`.

Answer (score 9):

`timeout` by default sends a SIGTERM to the program. Looks like `hcitool` doesn't handle that gracefully. Instead use SIGINT (equivalent to ctrl-c).

`sudo timeout -s SIGINT 5s hcitool -i hci0 lescan > file.txt`